# How to relevant in 2017 parse html links in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, parsing, laravel-5, html-parsing

Old way -> PHP Simple HTML DOM

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
foreach($html->find('div[class=name_class]') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

But now maybe have better way for parse html in laravel?

---

**example target**

```
  list_all_links = table [main class: table-list] [second class: quality, series]

   line with links (all td with [class: column])

   link = tr [class: item]
     quality = td [class: first, video]
     audio = td [class: audio]
     size = td [class: size]
     threads = td [class: thread] -> span [class: thread-one]
     download_url = td [class: last, download] -> a [data-default]
```

Comment: dom_crawler from simpfony is native in laravel 5+?
How parse with crawler?

Comment: And where write parser code? Tell the structure for this.

Comment: DOMDocument & DOMXPath has always been better than the simple_html_dom thing, i don't understand why people constantly use it. not to mention, development of that lib stopped years ago

Comment: @hanshenrik what you think about dom_crawler from simpfony?

Comment: never used it. btw if you wonder, here's the equivalent php DOM code:  ```$xp=new DOMXPath((@DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile('http://www.google.com/'))); foreach($xp->query("//div[@class='name_class']") as $div){echo $div->getAttribute("src").'<br/>';/*why does div tags have a src attribute?*/}```